# MySQL Substring in selection only when a character is present

Tags: mysql, substring, locate

A have a table that is populated by an automated process that contains several thousand company names from a third party feed. Most of the company names are just the name, but some have a hyphen after the company name. I am trying to do a select that will only return the company name. Right now I have two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor FROM feed_data;
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor)) FROM feed_data;
```

The first query gives me everything, the second query only gives me company names where there is a hyphen. I am looking for a way to get both.

Sample data:

```
vendor:
American Widgets
Bravo Widgets - The best widgets money can buy
```

Also, this query is actually a subquery part of a larger query that is populating a menu, so that may limit the possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this query:

```
select distinct 
     if(LOCATE(' - ', vendor)>0, SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor)), vendor)
from feed_data;
```

Comment: Perfect! Simple, straightforward and works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a union - one query for each half:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor))
FROM feed_data
where vendor like '%-%'
union
SELECT DISTINCT
    vendor
FROM feed_data
where vendor not like '%-%';
```

or, use `if()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    if (vendor like '%-%', SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor)), vendor)
FROM feed_data;
```

or, use `case`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    case
        when vendor like '%-%' then SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor))
        else vendor
    end
FROM feed_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be (It will give you all the vendor with a added field to mention whether it's with hyphen or not)

```
SELECT distinct vendor,
(case when LOCATE('-', vendor) >= 0 
then 'True'
else 'False' end) as IsVendorWithHiphen
FROM feed_data;
```

This One will give you the result of all vendor with `-` replaced wherever

```
select distinct 
(case when LOCATE('-', vendor) >= 0 then SUBSTRING(vendor, 1, LOCATE(' - ', vendor))
 else vendor) as myvendor from feed_data;
```